# Apple warns my app is using non-public selectors when submitting the app

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

The warning says "The app references non-public selectors in Payload/MyApp.app/MyApp:createEntity" .

Does this mean I've used `createEntity` from Apple's private API somewhere?

I've searched my project but all the place that I've used `createEntity` is using the project's custom selector. Can I ignore this warning and go ahead or find a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's detection of the use of private selectors is fairly crude and prone to false positives. You can probably just ignore the warning if you're not actually calling one of Apple's private APIs. If you want to go away, you can always rename your method.